# ASP NET: Output cache substitution with PageAdapter

Tags: c#, outputcache, substitution

I have the following problem:

I am trying to use output cache substitution (Substitution class), because I want that only one control in a page won´t be cached. But the content of this control is printed on the top of the page (before ). I think that it is because I am using a PageAdapter to make code accesible, and in the Render method I do the following:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    base.Render(hw);
    string html = sb.ToString();

    //Some operations with html code, like replace, cleaning, etc.
    output.Write(html);
}
```

The reason because of I want the html code in HtmlTextWriter in string format is to do the cleaning operations, because in the output variable received by the Render method, I can´t see the html code, therefore I can´t do these operations.

So, is there any way to use output cache substitution with this PageAdapter? Or is there any way to get html code from the output variable received by the Render method in the PageAdapter?